# Failed posting to Timeline. Error: {"message":"Call to a member function getImageInfo() on a non-object","type":"BadMethodCallException"}

Tags: facebook, wordpress

From last few days I a getting this error while adding a new Post on Wordpress, and Facebook plugin is not able to post it on Facebook Page.

> Failed posting to Timeline:
>
> Error: {"message":"Call to a member function getImageInfo() on a non-object","type":"BadMethodCallException"}

Now after upgrading Facebook plugin 1.2.1, I am getting a new error

Failed posting to your Facebook Timeline. Error: {"message":"Can only modify connections owned by this application","type":"Exception"}

Comment: I am seeing the same thing

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing.

Comment: @AnthonyWebb - I came up with a workaround for this. I call the share in a method which has a top param of $count. If the response fails (because of this specific reason) then I call the method again.

Obviously don't put it into a never ending loop. I allow 2 attempts and then treat it as a failure.

So far it works well, although I'm not 100% sure that it's the best idea and Facebook should have handled this themselves.